# how to show blob image in datatable, laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, image

I would like to see if you can help me with this. I want to display an image already saved in my database as a blob type in my datatable in Laravel 6.

my code clients.blade.php

```
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Observacion</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Grabacion</th>
                <th width="150px">Imagen</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
              </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>{{--
              @foreach ($client as $key => $value)

               <tr>

                <td>{{($key+1)}}</td>
                <td>{{($value["titulo"])}}</td>
                <td>{{($value["observacion"])}}</td>
                <td>{{($value["estado"])}}</td>
                <td>{{($value["grabacion"])}}</td>
                <td>

                <img src="{{($value["lugar_imagen"])}}" class="img-fluid" >
                </td>
```

...

code js(datatable).

columns: [
{
data: 'id',
name: 'id'
},
{

```
                    data: 'titulo',
            name: 'titulo'
            },
            {
                    data: 'observacion',
            name: 'observacion'
      },
    {
        data: 'estado',
        name: 'estado'
    },
    {
        data: 'grabacion',
        name: 'grabacion'
    },
      //columna mostrar imagen blob
            {
            data: 'lugar_imagen',
            name: 'lugar_imagen',
               render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
               var imgsrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
               return '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + imgsrc +'" " height="100px" width="100px">';
              }


            },

            orderable: false
      },
```

...

attentive to your comments. Thank

Answer (score 0):

You need in the td only put the base64 blob.

`<td> <img src="{{($value["lugar_imagen"])}}" class="img-fluid" ></td>`

is only

```
<td> {{($value["lugar_imagen"])}} </td>
```

Comment: enter the label, however it does not show me the datatable.
Other suggestions.